# Highslide opens new page in IE8 because of conflict with SoundManager

Tags: highslide

I have Highslide opening an iframe video, and it works well in all browsers but IE8 (I haven't tried IE9). In IE8, instead of the expansion window working, the video opens and plays in a new tab.

The page is complicated because it also uses an audio player program called SoundManager. When I remove the main SoundManager javascript link, Highslide works properly. Or I can remove a javascript function on the page called `soundmanager.setup`, and then Highslide works too. Clearly there's some conflict between the two programs. I've tried moving the scripts around on the page with no success. I've examined the code and can't find the conflict, since everything seems modular and contained. But I'm not a high-level javascript programmer, and clearly I'm missing something.

Have you seen SoundManager before, and have you encountered any conflicts? Can you suggest anything? If this is outside your job description, I understand. But it would be nice to get both programs to work on the same page.

If you'd like to look at the page, it's here: http://www.idesignmagic.com/silver/videotest.php  The cyan video play button under the page title fires the Highslide expansion.

There's some simple php in the code, which uses an array of audio titles and urls to display the SoundManager choices, but it has no impact on Highslide.

Any help you can give me will be appreciated.

[ Edit: I was wrong about `soundmanager.setup`. It just resets configuration defaults. I replaced the defaults with those in `setup` and removed `setup` from the main page. I get the same nonworking result in IE8. But perhaps this means that one of those setup choices is causing the problem. ]

Thanks.

Mark

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded [Soundmanager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) and tested in IE8 with [Highslide image](http://highslide.com/examples/no-border.html), [Highslide inline content](http://highslide.com/examples/inline.html) and [Highslide iframe](http://highslide.com/examples/iframe.html). The only combination that breaks is when using Soundmanager2 + page-player.js and Highslide iframe. Highslide inline content <strike>and Highslide image</strike> works well with Soundmanager2 + page-player.js. And you have to use Highslide iframe when opening a video page like yours.

When trying to open the Highslide iframe popup, I noticed that the popup starts to expand before the iframe breaks and the page opens in the browser. It almost seems like page-player.js triggers a “break out of iframe” function. This has nothing to do with the content of the page in the popup; I've also tested with a page containing nothing else than text in a paragraph.

I suggest that you contact the [Soundmanager2 support](https://getsatisfaction.com/schillmania/products/schillmania_soundmanager_2) about this to see if they have a solution.

**UPDATE 4. feb. 2013:**
After reading the latest comment from the Soundmanger2 support (https://getsatisfaction.com/schillmania/topics/conflict_between_soundmanager2_and_highslide_in_ie8#reply_11221943) I thought there might be a connection between putting the url in the href and this conflict. I tested once more with a Highslide image and saw that this actually failed too. I probably tested too quickly the other day. Highslide inline content still works, and Highslide inline content does not use url in the href. 
So the solution for this is to put the url for the page you want to open in the popup in the [src variable](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.src) in the onclick instead of the anchor’s href.

This means that you need to use this anchor to open the popup:

```
<a href='javascript:;' onclick='return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType:"iframe", src: 'video/iframe-test.html', width: 670, objectWidth: 670, objectHeight: 410, objectLoadTime: "after", preserveContent: false } )' class='highslide'>
    <img src='images/play-button-small.png' alt='Click for video' width='40' height='53' title='Click to enlarge' >
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, Hilde, for testing this. I'll try the Soundmanager people.  My best,  Mark

Comment: Followup to @RoadRash:  Hilde, I posted the question in the Soundmanager support forum, and got an interesting answer. See the post here: [link](https://getsatisfaction.com/schillmania/topics/conflict_between_soundmanager2_and_highslide_in_ie8)  Unfortunately their suggestions didn't solve the problem. But I think they pinpointed where the conflict occurs, and by moving a line of their code I got partial success. I reported back to them and said I'd update you as well. I don't know if this new information will suggest a solution, but I can only hope. Thanks. Mark

Comment: Thanks to @RoadRash: Works like a charm, Hilde. Bravo. I'll pass along the solution to the SoundManger people.  Many many thanks.  Mark